# How do I use containers.Map in Matlab with a cell array as the keys and a vector of integers as the values

Tags: matlab, dictionary, hash, containers

I have a cell array that contains words like 'a', 'b', and 'c' for example. What I want to be able to do is use Matlab's containers.Map to make a hash table that I can add values to for each key and be able to look them up quickly. I am able to do this if I do not initialize my containers.Map object beforehand as follows but it does not allow me (or at least I haven't found a way) to add more key/value pairs later and makes it so that I have to reinitialize the object during each iteration of a loop:

```
    key = {'a','b','c'};
    newmap = containers.Map(key,[1,2,3]);
```

My problem is that I need to be able to continually add new keys to the hash table and therefore cannot keep initializing the containers.Map object each time, I want one long hash table with all the keys and values that I get while in a loop.

Here is the code that I am trying to get working, I want to be able to add the keys to the containers.Map object newmap and their corresponding values at the same time. The keys are always strings in a cell array and the values are always integers:

```
    key = {'a','b','c'};
    val = [1,2,3];
    newmap = containers.Map(); % containers.Map object initialization
    newmap(key) = val;
```

My desired output would something like this:

```
    newmap(key)
    ans = 1 2 3
```

Attempts at solving this:

I have tried converting the cell array of keys using cellstr() and char() but haven't had any luck with these. I seem to keep getting this error when trying this:

```
    Error using containers.Map/subsref
    Specified key type does not match the type expected for this container.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
% Initialize
map = containers.Map('KeyType','char','ValueType','double');

% Assume you get these incrementally
key = {'a','b','c'};
val = [1,2,3];

% Add incrementally
for ii = 1:numel(key)
    map(key{ii}) = val(ii);
end
```

You can retrieve all values at once for a given set of keys, but you will get a cell array. No way around it, but you can convert with `cell2mat()`, or retrieve incrementally with a loop `map(key{ii})`

```
% Retrieve all
values(map,key)

ans = 
    [1]    [2]    [3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to avoid using a loop inside a loop because I have to run through the main loop over 50,000 times but I think this is the best solution to the problem thus far.

Comment: @user3716193 you can profile your application and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: @Oleg : Is it possible to add more elements to the map later if I initialise it as `newmap = containers.Map(keys,[1,2,3]);` ?

Comment: too low reputation to comment on posts. to get rid of cells after the values(map,key_subset) solution use
vv=[vv{:}]